# How to create and display an event only with Calendar Strip React Native npm package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, calendar, expo

I am a newbie in React Native and Expo world, and I have read the documentation of Calendars in React Native and Expo. I also saw a great npm package called Calendar Strip, which is what I want for my application. But I am confused on one thing, onDateSelected() props for this package, how can create an event or just display a  based on a specific date.

For example, July, 10th, 2022 should show a specific view container but other dates should not show that view as a component can be called on that particular date only. Hope I am clear on this. Appreciate your help.

Or if the same can be done with any well-known package or library, that would be appreciated.

Link for the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-strip

Answer (score 0):

the answer is "coding new app"! :))))
Any way, you should know that "Calendar Strip" is just an appearance for your code.
to add or delete event you can use [expo calendar](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/) .

Comment: also this doc can help you  [link](https://blog.expo.dev/5-easy-to-use-react-native-calendar-libraries-e830a97d5bf7)

Comment: Thanks, man. Appreciate your response and time. Definitely, coding from start and using a different library or package can change something now. 

Comment: You should use another library along with your current library which can "Provides an API"

Comment: Correct. I think this library has onDateSelectedProps, so I need to use or call another library or an API on this so that I can achieve the result for a particular date event.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong with my code. I was using the useEffect hook in the wrong way, I just had to put currentDate in the array to check if the componentDidUpdate based on my events, before it was empty [] and it was just working on componentDidMount, now I am passing [currentDate] to check if there was an event on this date. No fault with the Calendar-Strip package for React Native. It works absolutely fine. That's answers my question. If anyone needs any help with any future references, please bring the issue. Cheers.